# .net mysql connection fail -- The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call

Tags: c#, mysql, pointers, arguments

I was working a quite medium level project.Mysql connection and other things working perfectly but later on nearly end of the project somehow a magical error came suddenly.

-- The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call.

look at debug window :

```
'Santima Accounting Software.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Santima Accounting Software.vshost.exe Error: 0 : The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
The thread 'vshost.RunParkingWindow' (0x3ec) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0xe18) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[2040] Santima Accounting Software.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

-- I have tried a few things to solve it --

```
1 > restarting the computer.
   2 > Re installation of mysql connector.
   3 > reinstalling wamp.
   4 > searching google a lot and change a lot things in mysql settings.
   5 > Running project on different computer works fine but not in mine.
```

nothing helps me.I also found many has same problem like me but no solution anywhere.

My setting and how my project set up :

I'm using latest wamp for local environment.
I'm using both visual studio 2010,2012 express edition.
I'm using mysql connector latest.

user structure on mysql :

Please somebody help me getting out of this junk.

Comment: Do you have ipv4 and ipv6 addresses on your box?

Comment: no only ipv4.ipv6 is just set to automatically.

Comment: Is it possible that you are mixing ipv4 and ipv6 socket connections? How does your connection string look like? Is mysql listening to ipv4 and ipv6 addresses? Can you configure it to use only one?

Comment: public MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=santima;Uid=google;Pwd=;");

Comment: problem solved. Reinstall visual studio and wamp.reinstall if IIS and sql server installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although this question was reported in nearly two years ago, I plan to write my answer, I hope somebody find this information useful.
Here is my environment:

1. WIN7 X64
2. VS2012 ultimate
3. MYSQL Server 5.6.23 X86
4. MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.3  X86
5. MySQL Connector/NET 6.9.5  X86

when I tried the mysql connection through VS2012 IDE(NOT CODE), I got an error like this:

> the system detected an invalid pointer address in attemping to use a
>   pointer argument in a call

Finally, I found this problem related to LSP(layered service provider). My computer's LSP was destroyed by some Web Accelerator Software.

use the  CMD command line, execute the follow command to fix LSP:

```
netsh winsock reset
```

Of course, you can use other specialized tools to fix it.

Comment: We have tested this solution in Win8, VS2013, MySql 5.7, Connector 6.9.6. This actually fixed our problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just change in  the MySQL connection string of your config file from localhost to `127.0.0.1` it will solve your problem.